# Publisher 2007 default document page size

Tags: microsoft-publisher

On opening publisher the Publication 1 that it presents me with is not the page size that I want.  How do I change this default document so that when I open publisher next time it opens with the page size that I want?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open Publication 1, change the page size as required and Save as type: Publisher Template.

Comment: Thanks but that saves a new template and does not change the default

Answer (score 0):

Office templates are located by default :
**In Windows XP**
`C:\Documents and Settings\ user name \Application Data\Microsoft\Templates`

In **Windows Vista** or in **Windows 7** or **Windows 8**
`C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

Create a template accorging to your requirement and save it on your desktop. Then navigate to the above location and replace the existing template with your template ( ensure that the name is same).

Comment: Thanks for this but navigation string not correct and no Publisher templates found